"Device isnt compatible with this version" error shown on Google Play Console closed testing
We are uploading a flutter app on google play and it is in the closed testing phase. However most android testers who we send the link to download the app are facing this incompatibility issue as shown in the picture. What could be the issue?
screenshot of error on device
The users are on the email list and do have access to the closed testing version of the app and they should be able to download it as they were able to install the APK.
Can this be a potential issue?
warning on google play

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
